# Initializing turtles along a horizontal axis

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to setup turtles in a Netlogo model where the turtles are arranged randomly along the x-axis (from -16 to 16 on the interface) and along the y-axis at -16. Essentially across the bottom of the interface.
I've tried setxy xcor -16 16 ycor -16 but get "expected command" when checking the code.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to share your code

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the NetLogo Dictionary for `setxy`, one of the examples is:

```
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
```

That places the turtle in a random location. You want the `ycor` to be -16, so this would work:

```
setxy random-xcor -16.5
```

Even better, if you want to be able to adjust your world size and always be along the bottom, then:

```
setxy random-xcor min-pycor - 0.5
```

You may want to adjust the 0.5 a little to get them slightly off the bottom.

Comment: Thanks so much.  The last line of code works perfectly.